# regex to find a string or another string in search and then return one part of the searched with group

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string which is a file name, examples:

```
'20220213-0000-FSC-814-SC_VIRG_REFBAL_PRES_NPMINMAX-v1.xml'
'20220213-0000-F814-SC_VIRG_REFBAL_PRES_NPMINMAX-v1.xml'
```

I want to find a string with re.search which corresponds to `Fddd` or `FSC-ddd`.

I have a regex like this:

```
type_match = re.search(r'(F(\d{3}))|(FSC-(\d{3}))', string)
```

Later after I have found for example `FSC-814` , I want to get only the number from this found string, I used:

```
int(type_match.group(1))
```

but it does not work after I included or statement in the `re.search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
F(?:SC)?-?(\d{3})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/22bMWG/1).

*Details*:

- `F`  - an `F` char
- `(?:SC)?` - an optional `SC` char sequence
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `(\d{3})` - Capturing group 1: three digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7UzGmW):

```py
import re
texts = ['20220213-0000-FSC-814-SC_VIRG_REFBAL_PRES_NPMINMAX-v1.xml',
'20220213-0000-F814-SC_VIRG_REFBAL_PRES_NPMINMAX-v1.xml']
pattern = r'F(?:SC)?-?(\d{3})'
for text in texts:
    match = re.search(pattern, text)
    if match:
        print (match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
814
814
```